# How to efficnently store numbers in python as summarized expressions without losing any precision due to rounding errors

Tags: scipy, biginteger, symbolic-math, rounding-error

I have a number that I keep add/sub/mul/div over.  I currently store these operations as a list.

Now, I wish to summarize that list without losing precision at all.  So I expect to shrink the list, but not necessarily reduce it to a single number.

For example: ((5, add), (pi, mul)) will still summarize into itself.  I.e. it will not become any shorter, because of pi.  But ((5, add), (3.5, sub)) will summarize into ((1.5, add)).

Is there any way of doing this in python efficiently?

**note:** it does not have to be stored as a list.  It am flexible in any format of storage.  I just want similar semantics and maximum efficiency for a python code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with sympy. You'd need to keep transcendentals as sympy.Symbols.